# Values returned to javascript by webservice come as undefined

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, web-services, list

Guys I have a webservice in c# which is called in javascript ajax and values are returned to the javascript .Values are returned as list from webservice to javascript. But when I display values it shows me undefined for each value. Webservice is called  sucessfully I checked that using debugger.

My Webservice is like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for MyService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class MyService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    public MyService()
    {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
    [WebMethod]
    public List<myclass> dataRecieve(int roll, string name)
    {
        List<myclass> list = new List<myclass>();
        myclass mc = new myclass(9082, "Mubashir", "MCA1");

        list.Add(mc);
        mc = new myclass(9093, "Golu", "MCA1");
        list.Add(mc);
        mc = new myclass(872, "Fida", "MCA1");
        list.Add(mc);

        return list;

    }
}

public class myclass
{

    int roll;
    string name, address;

    public myclass(int r, string n, string a)
    {
        name = n;
        roll = r;
        address = a;

    }





}
```

My code for calling webservice and display values is like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowProgress() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var modal = $('<div />');
            modal.addClass("modal");
            $('body').append(modal);
            var loading = $(".loading");
            loading.show();
            var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
            var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
            loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
        }, 200);
    }
    $('form').live("submit", function () {
        ShowProgress();

    });
</script>
   <%-- 
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            SearchText();
        });
        function SearchText() {
            $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "index.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                        data: "{'Name':'" + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response(data.d);
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert("Error");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    </script>


       --%>

    <script type ="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btni").click(function () {

                var dataSent="{roll:"+1+",name:\""+"Mubashir\"}"
                $.ajax({

                    type: "Post",
                    url: "MyService.asmx/dataRecieve",
                    data: dataSent ,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        var studentInfo = response.d;
                        $("#output").empty();
                        $.each(studentInfo, function (index, Info) {
                            //alert(index);
                            //alert(index.Info);
                            $("#output").append(
                                '<strong>Roll : </strong>' + Info.roll + ' ' +
                                 '<strong>Name : </strong>' + Info.name + ' ' +
                                  '<strong>Address : </strong>' + Info.address + '<br/> '
                                );

                        });



                    },

                    failure: function (msg) {


                        $("#output").text(msg);

                    }




                });



            });


});
    </script>
<style type="text/css">
    .modal
    {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: black;
        z-index: 99;
        opacity: 0.8;
        filter: alpha(opacity=80);
        -moz-opacity: 0.8;
        min-height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .loading
    {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10pt;
        border: 1px solid blue ;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        background-color: White;
        z-index: 999;
        border-radius :6px;
    }
</style>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
        .ErrorControl
        {
            background-color: #FBE3E4;
            border: solid 1px Red;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <button id="btni" type ="button"  >Get Students</button>
       <div id="output"></div>
  </form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting your data before running autocomplete:

```
    function SearchText() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "index.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
            data: "{'Name':'" + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
                    source: data
                });
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });

    }
```